# downloading and caching images from url asynchronously

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell, nsurl

I'm trying to download images from my firebase database and load them into collectionviewcells. The images download, however I am having trouble having them all download and load asynchronously.

Currently when I run my code the *last* image downloaded loads. However, if I update my database the collection view updates and the new last user profile image also loads in but the remainder are missing.

I'd prefer to not use a 3rd party library so any resources or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code that handles the downloading:

```
func loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(_ urlString: String) {

    self.image = nil

//        checks cache
    if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString) as? UIImage {
        self.image = cachedImage
        return
    }

    //download
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

        //error handling
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as NSString)

                self.image = downloadedImage
            }

        })

    }).resume()
}
```

I believe the solution lies somewhere in reloading the collectionview I just don't know where exactly to do it.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Here is where the function is being called; my `cellForItem at indexpath`

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: userResultCellId, for: indexPath) as! FriendCell

    let user = users[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameLabel.text = user.name

    if let profileImageUrl = user.profileImageUrl {

            cell.profileImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(profileImageUrl)
    }

    return cell
}
```

The only other thing that I believe could possibly affect the images loading is this function I use to download the user data, which is called in `viewDidLoad`, however all the other data downloads correctly.

```
func fetchUser(){
    Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let user = User()
            user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)

            self.users.append(user)
            print(self.users.count)

             DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
              })
        }


    }, withCancel: nil)

}
```

**Current Behavior:**

As for the current behavior the last cell is the only cell that displays the downloaded profile image; if there are 5 cells, the 5th is the only one that displays a profile image. Also when I update the database, ie register a new user into it, the collectionview updates and displays the newly registered user correctly with their profile image in addition to the old last cell that downloaded it's image properly. The rest however, remain without profile images.

Comment: Can you show your CollectionViewController?

Comment: @javimuu I included where the function is being called.

Comment: use sdwebimage library to load image easy.

Comment: Use sdwebImage library for caching the image.

Comment: But the asynchronous retrieval mechanism is basically OK (though I'd instantiate the `UIImage` and update cache in background and only dispatch the `self.image = image` to the main queue.) Your problem is likely unrelated. Sure, there's lots of improvements to this extension (e.g. if the user scrolls quickly through the collection view, you're going to see images flicker, showing results for previous index paths, you're going to get backlogged with requests for index paths that are no longer visible, etc.). But before we tackle improvements, let's figure out what the current problem is.

Comment: Also, very minor, likely unrelated, problem in `cellForItemAt`: If there's no image URL for the cell, you are leaving the old profile image there. You probably want else clause to set the profile image to `nil` if there's no image URL.

Comment: @Rob thanks for the pointers, I will set the profile image to nil. Also I updated the question to include a more detailed description of the current behavior. It's located at the bottom of the post.

Comment: @Rob I just went over everything and I found the issue. The individual urls were set up properly however the database reference was not. Each image was being saved into the database as "profileImage", Therefore every time a user was registered the old database reference was overriden with the new users values. I have fixed that issue and now each profile image shows correctly. One last thing, you mentioned something earlier about seeing images flicker from fast scrolling any ideas on how to fix that? Or could you point me to a post if it's already been answered. Thanks again.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I know you found your problem and it was unrelated to the above code, yet I still have an observation. Specifically, your asynchronous requests will carry on, even if the cell (and therefore the image view) have been subsequently reused for another index path. This results in two problems:

1. If you quickly scroll to the 100th row, you are going to have to wait for the images for the first 99 rows to be retrieved before you see the images for the visible cells. This can result in really long delays before images start popping in.
2. If that cell for the 100th row was reused several times (e.g. for row 0, for row 9, for row 18, etc.), you may see the image appear to flicker from one image to the next until you get to the image retrieval for the 100th row.

Now, you might not immediately notice either of these are problems because they will only manifest themselves when the image retrieval has a hard time keeping up with the user's scrolling (the combination of slow network and fast scrolling). As an aside, you should always test your app using the network link conditioner, which can simulate poor connections, which makes it easier to manifest these bugs.

Anyway, the solution is to keep track of (a) the current `URLSessionTask` associated with the last request; and (b) the current `URL` being requested. You can then (a) when starting a new request, make sure to cancel any prior request; and (b) when updating the image view, make sure the URL associated with the image matches what the current URL is.

The trick, though, is when writing an extension, you cannot just add new stored properties. So you have to use the associated object API to associate these two new stored values with the `UIImageView` object. I personally wrap this associated value API with a computed property, so that the code for retrieving the images does not get too buried with this sort of stuff. Anyway, that yields:

```swift
extension UIImageView {
    private static var taskKey = 0
    private static var urlKey = 0

    private var savedTask: URLSessionTask? {
        get { objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UIImageView.taskKey) as? URLSessionTask }
        set { objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIImageView.taskKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC) }
    }

    private var savedUrl: URL? {
        get { objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UIImageView.urlKey) as? URL }
        set { objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIImageView.urlKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC) }
    }

    func setImage(with url: URL?, placeholder: UIImage? = nil) {
        // cancel prior task, if any

        weak var oldTask = savedTask
        savedTask = nil
        oldTask?.cancel()

        // reset image view’s image

        self.image = placeholder

        // allow supplying of `nil` to remove old image and then return immediately

        guard let url else { return }

        // check cache

        if let cachedImage = ImageCache.shared.image(forKey: url.absoluteString) {
            self.image = cachedImage
            return
        }

        // download

        savedUrl = url
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in
            self?.savedTask = nil

            // error handling

            if let error {
                // don't bother reporting cancelation errors

                if (error as? URLError)?.code == .cancelled {
                    return
                }

                print(error)
                return
            }

            guard let data, let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data) else {
                print("unable to extract image")
                return
            }

            ImageCache.shared.save(image: downloadedImage, forKey: url.absoluteString)

            if url == self?.savedUrl {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.image = downloadedImage
                }
            }
        }

        // save and start new task

        savedTask = task
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Also, note that you were referencing some `imageCache` variable (a global?). I would suggest an image cache singleton, which, in addition to offering the basic caching mechanism, also observes memory warnings and purges itself in memory pressure situations:

```swift
class ImageCache {
    private let cache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
    private var observer: NSObjectProtocol?

    static let shared = ImageCache()

    private init() {
        // make sure to purge cache on memory pressure

        observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            forName: UIApplication.didReceiveMemoryWarningNotification,
            object: nil,
            queue: nil
        ) { [weak self] notification in
            self?.cache.removeAllObjects()
        }
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer!)
    }

    func image(forKey key: String) -> UIImage? {
        return cache.object(forKey: key as NSString)
    }

    func save(image: UIImage, forKey key: String) {
        cache.setObject(image, forKey: key as NSString)
    }
}
```

---

A bigger, more architectural, observation: One really should decouple the image retrieval from the image view. Imagine you have a table where you have a dozen cells using the same image. Do you really want to retrieve the same image a dozen times just because the second image view scrolled into view before the first one finished its retrieval? No.

Also, what if you wanted to retrieve the image outside of the context of an image view? Perhaps a button? Or perhaps for some other reason, such as to download images to store in the user’s photos library. There are tons of possible image interactions above and beyond image views.

Bottom line, fetching images is not a method of an image view, but rather a generalized mechanism of which an image view would like to avail itself. An asynchronous image retrieval/caching mechanism should generally be incorporated in a separate “image manager” object. It can then detect redundant requests and be used from contexts other than an image view.

FWIW, you can see an example of this sort of image manager (where subsequent requests for the same image do not generate duplicative network requests) in WWDC 2021 [Protect mutable state with Swift actors](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133/?time=719), tap on the “Code” tab, and scroll down to `ImageDownloader` snippet at 11:59.

---

As you can see, the asynchronous retrieval and caching is starting to get a little more complicated, and this is why we generally advise considering established asynchronous image retrieval mechanisms like [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) or [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) or [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage). These guys have spent a lot of time tackling the above issues, and others, and are reasonably robust. But if you are going to “roll your own,” I would suggest something like the above at a bare minimum.