# Nil while caching images

Tags: ios, swift, caching

I've been able to solve the issue of caching images to improve scroll performance in my app. However nil is found when it tries to add it to [cache](https://ibb.co/N6tSWkH). Also how can I add a placeholder image for images that failed to load or aren't available ?

```
let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

    extension UIImageView {
    
        func downloadImage(from imgURL: String) -> URLSessionDataTask? {
            guard let url = URL(string: imgURL) else { return nil }
    
            // set initial image to nil so it doesn't use the image from a reused cell
            image = nil
    
            // check if the image is already in the cache
            if let imageToCache = imageCache.object(forKey: imgURL as NSString) {
                self.image = imageToCache
                return nil
            }
    
            // download the image asynchronously
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if let err = error {
                    print(err)
                    return
                }
    
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // create UIImage
                    let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data!)
                    // add image to cache
                    imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: imgURL as NSString)
                    self.image = imageToCache
                }
            }
            task.resume()
            return task
        }
    }
```

Comment: For the sake of future readers, previous question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71274835/1271826).

Comment: @Rob This a different type of question.

Comment: I wasn’t marking it as a duplicate. I was letting future readers know what research/help you have gotten previously.

Comment: @Rob sorry about that

Comment: No worries. By the way, you will still have the performance problem if, for example, you use this in a table view cell and the user scrolls quickly. You’re going to get backlogged. I’d suggest you cancel prior images (as [shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45178305/downloading-and-caching-images-from-url-asynchronously) that I linked to my answer to your prior question).

Comment: @Rob Thank you so much. Dealing with images is a huge pain with URL session.

Comment: Yeah, it’s a non-trivial exercise to do properly. That’s why we often advise considering third party solutions like AlamofireImage, Kingfisher, SDWebImage. 

Comment: @Rob One more thing, How can I add a "No Results Text" to the table view when search term doesn't exist ?

Comment: A pattern that I’ve used before is to check if there are no results, and if so, show a `NoResultsCell`. E.g., `numberOfRowsInSection` return `results.count == 0 ? 1 : results.count` and have `cellForRowAt` also check if `results.count == 0` and if so, generate the `NoResultsCell`, otherwise generate the standard results cell. The other approach, which I tend to do more often, is to have a “no results” view above the table view (not in it) whose is `isHidden` is set to `results.count == 0`. I’ve done both, but lean towards the latter pattern because it’s easier to customize the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. Just supply `placeholder` as parameter to function and use it instead of `nil` to initialize the `image`.
2. Do that after checking the cache (because there’s no point in using the placeholder if you found desired image in the cache).
3. Avoid use of `!` forced unwrapping operator.
4. Check that `UIImage(data:)` found an image in the `guard` statement (and on the session queue, not the main thread).

Thus:

```swift
let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

extension UIImageView {
    func downloadImage(from imgURL: String, placeholder: UIImage? = nil) -> URLSessionDataTask? {
        guard let url = URL(string: imgURL) else { return nil }
        
        // check if the image is already in the cache
        if let imageToCache = imageCache.object(forKey: imgURL as NSString) {
            image = imageToCache
            return nil
        }
        
        // set initial image to placeholder so it doesn't use the image from a reused cell
        image = placeholder
        
        // download the image asynchronously
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
            guard 
                let data = data, 
                error == nil,
                let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data)
            else {
                print(error ?? URLError(.badServerResponse))
                return
            }
            
            imageCache.setObject(imageToCache, forKey: imgURL as NSString)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = imageToCache
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        return task
    }
}
```