# Swift - Return Generic Type/Data

Tags: ios, swift, generics, urlsession

I have URLSession shared instance that fetches data. It returns a generic type. Everything works fine when I'm fetching data from a server and displaying it. But when I fetch an image I need to return the Generic Type as the data. How can I return the generic type/data so that it can be used to create the image in the imageView?

UIImageView:

```
extension UIImageView {
    
    func loadImage(with url: URL) {
        
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: url.absoluteString as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
            self.image = cachedImage
            return
        }
        
        URLSessionManager.fetchData(with: url, isImageFetch: true) { (result: Result<Data, SessionDataTaskError>) in

            switch result {

            case .failure(let error):

                print(error)

            case .success(let data):

                guard let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data) else {
                    print("image data is nil")
                    return
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async{ [weak self] in

                    imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: url.absoluteString as AnyObject)
                    self?.image = downloadedImage
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

URLSessionManager:

```
class URLSessionManager {
    
    static let shared = URLSessionManager()
    
    static func fetchData<T: Decodable>(with url: URL, isImageFetch: Bool = false, completion: @escaping (Result<T, SessionDataTaskError>)->Void) { // SessionDataTaskError is just an Enum
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(SessionDataTaskError.failedIssue(error)))
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(.failure(SessionDataTaskError.dataIsNil))
                return
            }
            
            if isImageFetch {

                // *** How can I return the generic type/data so that it can be used to create the image in the imageView? ***
                return
            }

            do {
                
                let genericType = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                
                completion(.success(genericType))
                
            } catch {
                
                completion(.failure(SessionDataTaskError.catchIssue(error)))
                
                guard let err = error as? DecodingError else {
                    debugPrint("decodingError-:", error)
                    return
                }
                
                switch err {
                case .typeMismatch(let key, let value):
                    print("decodingError-Mismatch: \(key), value \(value) and ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                case .valueNotFound(let key, let value):
                    print("decodingError-ValueNotFound: \(key), value \(value) and ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                case .keyNotFound(let key, let value):
                    print("decodingError-KeyNotFound(: \(key), value \(value) and ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                case .dataCorrupted(let key):
                    print("decodingError-DataCorrupted: \(key), and ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                default:
                    print("decodingError-UnknownError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
            
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: The `fetchData<T: Decodable>` is for performing `JSONDecoder` on the body of the response. But an image is not JSON, so it does not make sense to call that method when the response is actually an image. Generally, you would have a separate implementation that returns a `Data` or a `UIImage`.

Comment: @Rob that's what I was doing at first. In the ImageView extension method I used a separate URLSession but I thought that I would be able to use just 1 shared URLSession throughout the entire app. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I just followed your comments and they both work! THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fetchData<T: Decodable>` is for performing `JSONDecoder` on the body of the response. But an image is not JSON, so it does not make sense to call that method when the response is actually an image. Generally, you would have a separate implementation that returns a `Data` or a `UIImage`.

So I would have a non-generic `fetchData` that retrieves a `Data` upon success. Then I would have a generic `fetchObject` that calls `fetchData` decodes the generic with `JSONDecoder`. And I would have a non-generic `fetchImage` that also calls `fetchData`, but which returns a `UIImage`.

---

As an aside, I would be very careful with `loadImage(with:)`. You do not just want to just update the `UIImageView`, because there is a risk (especially with collection and table views) where cells might be reused in the intervening time, which can cause very strange results where the wrong image may appear if you are scrolling quickly through the collection/table view). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45183939/1271826 for an example of the use of “associated objects” to keep track of pending request, if any. This pattern also avoids it from getting backlogged if the user scrolls quickly.

Comment: for the cell issue, I've been using this and it's been working perfectly `var task: URLSessionDataTask?`; `func setImageView(with url: URL) { task = URLSession.shared.dataTask (...){...}; task?.resume()`; and in `prepareToReuse()` I set `task?.cancel(); task = nil; imageView.image = nil`. Basically I have a task variable that is of type URLSessionDataTask, when the cell fetches the image it calls the func which inits the task, but if the user is fast scrolling prepareForReuse cancels the task and sets it to nil. I never have the issue you described because of what happens in prepareForReuse

Comment: It's a but different from using `loadImage(...)` and I actually use `inout` to pass the `task` to the `URLSessionManager` class. It was too much code to type so I summarized it in the comment above.

Comment: Yes, that pattern of saving the `URLSessionTask` and canceling when reused is precisely what I was talking about. I only mentioned it because the code snippet in the question didn’t contemplate this. Sounds like you’ve got it covered in your actual code base, though.